# Add to Redis Set

Tags: redis

I am reading [Redis, from the ground up](http://blog.mjrusso.com/2010/10/17/redis-from-the-ground-up.html) and I can't understand this part:

```
redis> MULTI
OK
redis> SET article.technology.1021 "In today's technology news, ..."
QUEUED
redis> SADD article.technology 1021
QUEUED
redis> PUBLISH new.article.technology 1021
QUEUED
redis> EXEC
1. OK
2. (integer) 1
3. (integer) 1
```

why there is a SET and then a SADD?, and why the SADD call receives a 1021, instead of the value of the article?

Comment: The general idea is how to hack keys and types to get pseudo relational databases. Mentally mask out 'article.technology' with 'X' and you have a map of 'X.id-number'; a set of 'X' with all id-numbers for that X, and a queue 'new.X' that publishes new 'id-number's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command - `SET article.technology.1021 "In today's technology news, ..."` - is used to set the article's content/topic as the value of a key called `article.technology.1021`. Note that the article's id is a part of the key's name.

Then, the next command, i.e. `SADD article.technology 1021`, adds that article (id) to the set called `article. technology`. That set can be used to retrieve all the articles (actual ids) that belong to the technology category, e.g. by doing `SMEMBERS article.technology`. The response will be all of the article ids that are in that set (belong to the technology category) so you could, potentially, fetch or process those.

Comment: thanks a lot, is really easy after you explained it.